# If ad = bc, (a, b) = 1, (c, d) = 1, and a, b, c, and d are all positive, show a = c and b = d.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

So far I have that

Since we known that (a,b) = 1 by definition we can write it as ax+by=1. We also know that (c,d) = 1, so cx+dy=1. Since they are both equal to 1 I can set them equal to each other where ax+by=cx+dy.

Now I am unsure what my next steps would be to prove this. It seems that it would only work if the gcd of every variable is 1. But again, I am unsure how to show that.

Comment: There is no reason why the values of $x,y$ in $ax+by=1$ should be the same as the values of $x,y$ in $cx+dy=1$.  You could write $ax_1+by_1=cx_2+dy_2$, but this is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: As an additional hint to what was already provided below, for positive integers, if $x\mid y$ then $x\leq y$.  If you also have $y\mid x$ then $y\leq x$.  Now, if $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $a\mid ad$, so $a\mid bc$, so $a\mid c$ because...

See if you can provide the reason for the last step and then complete the proof.

Comment: How did you know that $a\mid ad$ ?

Comment: Do you know what $\mid$ means?

Comment: Yes, it means a divides ad.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. Where in the information provided were you able to get $a\mid ad$

Comment: Tell me two integers, positive integers, any two you like.

Comment: Alright,10 and 45.

Comment: Is it true that $10\mid10\times45$?  How do you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35208/discussion-between-bella-and-david).

Comment: ok$\,\!\,\!\,\!$